# TypeScript compiler API get value / type of import

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Consider the following code:

```
// file1
export const VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 1080;

// file2
import { VIEWPORT_HEIGHT } from '../../constants/app';
```

While processing file2, how can I get the value / type of VIEWPORT_HEIGHT? Given that it's a constant, its type will be `1080`, not `number`. I'm trying to accomplish the same as VSCode which shows the constant value when you hover over the import:

[image]

While processing the import, I can analyse the following AST:

```
ImportDeclaration > ImportClause > NamedImports > ImportSpecifier > Identifier
```

I have access to the `program` that webpack's ts-loader passes to [getCustomTransformers](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#getcustomtransformers) and thus I have access to the type checker by doing:

```
let checker = program.getTypeChecker();
```

But I'm unable to reach the value / type. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out.

I can pass any declaration to the type checker to obtain its value. Here's an example:

```
const ts = require('typescript');

function createConstInlinerTransformer(program) {
  const factory = ts.factory;
  const checker = program.getTypeChecker();

  function transformerFactory(context) {
    return {
      transformSourceFile(sourceFile) {
        const visitor = function (node) {
          // The sourceFile node contains the following:
          // sourceFile.symbol.exports
          // sourceFile.locals
          // We can use these to obtain the values of variables and imports.

          // import
          const firstImportClause = sourceFile.statements[0].importClause;
          checker.getTypeAtLocation(firstImportClause.namedBindings.elements[0].symbol.declarations[0])

          // local const
          const localVar = sourceFile.locals.get('someVar');
          checker.getTypeAtLocation(localVar.valueDeclaration);

          // exported const
          const exportedVar = sourceFile.symbol.exports.get('someExportedVar');
          checker.getTypeAtLocation(exportedVar.valueDeclaration)

          return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, context);
        };

        return ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visitor);
      },
    };
  }
  return transformerFactory;
}

module.exports = { createConstInlinerTransformer };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but this should work:

```js
export const VIEWPORT: {HEIGHT: number} = {HEIGHT: 1080};
```

Then use it with:

```
export { VIEWPORT } from '../../constants/app';
console.log(VIEWPORT['HEIGHT']);
```

Comment: No, that doesn't answer my question. My question involves the usage of TypeScript's compiler API: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Comment: Can you try to query the type-checker using the object-style const I wrote?